# Can we add multiple passes to wallet at once?

Tags: passbook, wallet

I'm using php-pkpass library to create pass. Now can add only 1 pass at a time and I want to add multiple passes at once.
Is it possible to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: How are you trying to add them? Are you using an app or opening via a URL in safari?

Comment: I'm opening URL in safari.

Answer (score 2):

I keep seeing "NO" answers but I keep seeing companies(such as train companies) doing that just fine.
So I'm really curious as to why you can't but they can.

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple NO

You can use for your own pkpass application.

The Passbook App scanner will only allow you to add a pass if ALL of the following are true:

The QR code contains a URL

The URL scheme is https and the server certificate is valid and can be authenticated (I.e not self signed)

The URL returns a Content-Type header of application/vnd.apple.pkpass

The URL body contains a single .pkpass bundle

Adding multiple passes via the Passbook App scanner from a single QR code is currently not possible. The only way to add multiple passes is via your own app using the addPasses:withCompletionHandler: method of the PKPassLibrary class.